# Move tkinter view on widget

Tags: python, tkinter

There is a way for directly move the current view of the Canvas to a widget out of the current visual?

I mean if i have a canvas with `width=5000` and `height=1000` and on my screen i have canvas window that shows the portion `screen width=300` and `screen height=300` there is a function for move the view to an element that is at coords `(600,700)` of the canvas withot using the scrollbars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrollbars don't do anything magic. To make a scrollbar work, they are simply configured to call the `xview` or `yview` method of the canvas. There's nothing preventing you from directly calling those methods yourself.

The `xview_moveto` and `yview_moveto` take a fraction as an argument, and scrolls the canvas so that that fraction is above or to the left of the visible portion of the canvas. For example, to see an element at an x coordinate of 600 on a canvas with a drawable area 1000 pixels wide you can use the fraction 600/1000.

The `xview_scroll` and `yview_scroll` take a number and a string describing that number. The string should be either "units" or "pages". Thus, a value of 10 and a string of "units" will scroll the view by 10 pixels in the x direction.

Here is an example using the `moveto` methods. It creates a canvas with a scrollable region that is 5000 pixels wide and 1000 pixels tall, but with a displayable area of 300x300. It then draws a rectangle starting at 600,700, and then scrolls it into view. Even though the rectangle is drawn "off screen", it will appear in the upper-left of the canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300, scrollregion=(0,0,5000,1000))
canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas.create_rectangle(600, 700, 650, 750, fill="red")
canvas.yview_moveto(700/1000)
canvas.xview_moveto(600/5000)

root.mainloop()
```